# Convert Jupyter Notebook to Latex with margin handled automatically

Tags: conversion, pythontex

Is there a way to convert Jupyter Notebook to `.tex` with margins being taken care automatically.

I have some lines that overshoots the margin on LaTex. Is it possible to automatically put new line for such situations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you give us a small example Notebook that shows the problem.

Comment: Actually, this may be off topic, since the "LaTex" that Jupyter uses is MathJax. MathJax is not LaTeX, but uses LaTeX syntax.  If you're talking about conversion to LaTeX with `pandoc` using `nbconvert` then it *is* on topic.